# How to pass data from one class to another in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am passing some data from one class to another. I have a button which upon being tapped passed the data to another stateful class without Route or Navigator.

How to pass the data 'onTap' of button from one class to another in flutter ???

Thanks in Advance.

This is link where is whole code: https://dpaste.de/mfyz#L456

i have this button on stateful class, i want to pass a flag ontap of this button.

```
 new Expanded(child: Center(
                            child: !_canShowButton ? new MaterialButton(onPressed: (){
                              TabApp tab= new TabApp(valueReview);

                            },
                              child: new Text("Review For Submit",style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 21.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                              ),),
                              color: Colors.greenAccent,
                              height: 43.0,
                              textColor: Colors.blue,
                              splashColor: Colors.red,):SizedBox()
                          )),
```

i have this stateful class where i wants a flag to pass:

```
class TabApp extends StatefulWidget {

   TabApp(int valueReview);



  @override
  _TabAppState createState() => _TabAppState();
  }

  class _TabAppState extends State<TabApp> with TickerProviderStateMixin{

   }
```

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: i edit my question @Augusto if you need something more than you can tell me.

Comment: Can you share the use case? You want to send the data to other class then what, are you opening other class file or not?

Comment: @VickySalunkhe  Sir i have TabBar class,there has two tabs one is Question 2nd is Review and i have another class Questions class. Questions class has view pager which have many questions. i want disable Review and i already done. i want to enable Review Tab on last question when i press on some button. and i want to pass a int or flag from button which is in Question class to TabBar class when flag 0 Review tab is enable otherwise disable.

Comment: @mathronaut  i mention already without Route or Navigator.

Comment: It's sounds simple, just create a var and use `tab.yourVar = val` on your `onPressed: ()`. If you post whole code would help more.

Comment: https://dpaste.de/mfyz#L456  this is link where is whole code @Augusto

Comment: How you are making the navigation?

Comment: which navigation ? @Augusto

Comment: You questions are a bit confused. First, which classes are you working, I don't understanded, which class is your origin and destiny of data? You can't browse from a screen to another screen? Just pass data, alright?

Comment: You seen whole code and there are two stateful classes. In first class you can see that i'm using TabBar and 2nd class is Questions which is calling by first Tab and i have disabled my another Tab till the last element of list when it comes on the last element of list another tab would be enabled.

Comment: i have one screen which has 3 classes. 1st class TabAPP, 2nd class Questions, 3rd class ReviewActivity. 1st class is only for showing tabs 1st is QuestionsTab 2nd is ReviewTab , but now ReviewTab is disable. 2nd class Questions which is my first tab of TabApp has many dynamically questions with options,i have two bottons next or previous which is working with pageview, when my last question is showing on screen button replace by another button "Review for Submit".i want when i press "Review for Submit" button 2nd tab should be enable. What should i do to enable this tab ??

Answer (score 0):

To pass data between classes like the way it seems you're trying to do you should look into architectural patterns such as BLoC or [ScopedModel](https://pub.dev/packages/scoped_model) (or one of the many other options available). ScopedModel is pretty simple and straightforward.  If you want to use the standard library and not involve another package then you could use a plain vanilla InheritedWidget. Personally I'd recommend ScopedModel since it's really simple. If you do end up passing data between routes later on then be sure you place the model above the MaterialApp widget (or CupertinoApp).

```
class TabApp extends StatefulWidget {

   TabApp(int valueReview);

   final int valueReview;



  @override
  _TabAppState createState() => _TabAppState();
  }

  class _TabAppState extends State<TabApp> with TickerProviderStateMixin{

   }
```

Then call your variable in the State by using `widget.valueReview`

Comment: Actually, I'm new on Flutter. I don't know how to do this. please can you understand me with some example ?

Comment: This is a very large topic with a plethora of information available online along with more options for architectural patterns that you can use in Flutter. These are just two common ones.

Comment: edited answer to show how to pass data down to children Stateful widgets.